# Is there an option in Windows 10/11 to prefer similar IPv6 source address for outbound connections?

Tags: windows, networking, ipv6

I have a multihoming setup with 2 IPv6 GUAs on the same interface, each from a different ISP. My edge router does source-based policy routing, so is there a way to tell Windows to use the same ISP (judging from the destination address) whenever possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Isn't that already the default behavior? I recall "longest prefix match" was one of the rules in source address selection.

Comment: @u1686_grawity :( Silly me. Just tested it and you are right. Gonna keep this question for future reference.